# Linking a ComboBox with an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, observablecollection

I am trying to link a `combobox` with my `ObservableCollection`, however this does not seem to work, I have looked around and tried other ways that the internet is saying, but I can't seem to get it to work

```
public class UserData
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Application
    {
        get
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}

private static ObservableCollection<UserData> _userdata = new ObservableCollection<UserData>();
    public static ObservableCollection<UserData> Userdata
    {
        get { return _userdata; }
        set { _userdata = value; }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Height="24" 
   Margin="5,3,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Width="112" 
   x:Name="cbApplications" 
   DropDownClosed="cbApplications_DropDownClosed" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Userdata}"/>
```

Would anyone be able to support me in this matter?

Comment: how Userdata is updated?

Comment: You should never have a setter for a `ObservableCollection<>`.  Doing so orphans the data and the view will never see it.  Allocate it once in your constructor

Comment: @MickyD That's not true when you fire the PropertyChanged event for the Userdata property.

Comment: @Clemens that defeats the whole point of an _observable_ and is a bad practice

Comment: @Clemens Well everything is someones opinion.  Incorrect.  Irrelevant.  No evidence.   Speculation serves no purpose

Comment: @Clemens I'm glad you agree with me regarding your 3rd point. ;)  Anyway I'm off to play World of Warships

Comment: @MickyD I don't agree with you, I just don't like to continue this discussion. As always, my point is just to try to avoid that people here get a wrong impression of what is "right" and what is "wrong". OP shouldn't get the impression that having a setter for an ObservableCollection is in any way "wrong". It may be redundant, but it is not an error. No data will be orphaned, that simple.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a view model class like this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<UserData> UserData { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<UserData>();

    private UserData selectedUserData;

    public UserData SelectedUserData
    {
        get { return selectedUserData; }
        set
        {
            selectedUserData = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedUserData)));
        }
    }
}
```

and bind to it like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserData}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserData}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Text"/>
```

In the constructor of your MainWindow (or some other appropriate place), initialize the view model and assign it to the DataContext property of the Window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.UserData.Add(new UserData { Text = "User 1" });
    vm.UserData.Add(new UserData { Text = "User 2" });
    vm.UserData.Add(new UserData { Text = "User 3" });
    vm.SelectedUserData = vm.UserData[1];

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

Note that since you can set the ComboBox's `DisplayMemberPath` property (or declare an ItemTemplate) it's not necessary to override the `ToString` method of the UserData class.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the static, is there a reason for that?
Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in you class.
Then add in your

```
set { _userdata = value; OnPropertyChanged("Userdata"); }
```

Also, for cleanliness you should move your Closed command to binding or ICommand unless you are needing to do something UI specific only that has no data content associated.

Let me know if that doesn't fix you.

Also a lot of times I like to make a base class to handle this.

```
 public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //MEMBERS
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    //PROPERTIES
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Then you can call it from your setter like:

OnPropertyChanged();
without any params.